# How to perfom recursive query without cursors

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

### Person

```
id
----
1
2
```

### Order

```
Id   Qty
---------
1    3
1    0
2    2
```

How can I get all persons with orders greater than 0 that have never placed a 0 order? So the result of this would only Person.Id 2

I think I know how to do this with cursors but want to find a different way.

EDIT:

I think in an attempt to make the example short and easy to read I forgot one detailed.. I am not really filtering by Id's. I am filtering by text.

The correct example would be a Customer table, with an order table, in which i want all who have ordered chicken, but have not ordered chicken and fish.

### Customer

```
id
----
1
2
3
```

### Order

```
Id   Dish
----------------
1    chicken
2    chicken
2    fish
3    fish
```

So the result should only be Customer Id 1

Comment: I assume the `Id` column in `Order` references a `Person`'s `Id`, correct?

Comment: might want to add person.id 3 to your table to better illustrate the "persons with orders greater than 0" constraint.

Comment: (Added details from comments on mynameiscoffey's answer.)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing recursive about solving the question.

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM PERSON p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM ORDER o
                   WHERE o.id = p.id
                     AND o.qty = 0)
```

### Using NOT IN

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM PERSON p
 WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT o.id
                      FROM ORDER o
                     WHERE o.qty = 0)
```

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL

```
   SELECT p.id
     FROM PERSON p
LEFT JOIN ORDER o ON o.id = p.id
                 AND o.qty = 0
    WHERE o.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Be aware that if you have a customer of ID 4 that hasn't ordered EITHER chicken or fish both NOT EXISTS and NOT IN examples above will return id 4 anyway  (or id 3 with no orders, as originally written)  as they only check that you HAVEN'T ordered fish/nothing, not that you also did at least order chicken/something

Answer (score 0):

It's not recursive, but it *is* a "different way":

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM Order 
WHERE Qty > 0 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Order WHERE Qty = 0)
```

The inner query gets a list of ids that have placed zero orders, and the outer query gets a list of ids that have (a) placed *non*-zero orders, and (b) are not in the first list.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id
from Person p
left join Order o on p.id = o.id
group by p.id
having count(o.id) > 0 and min(o.qty) > 0
```

Comment: I think in an attempt to make the example short and easy to read I forgot one detailed..  I am not really filtering by Id's.   I am filtering by text.

Comment: The correct example would be a Customer table, with an order table, in which i want all who have ordered chicken, but have not ordered chicken and fish.  


1,chicken
2,chicken
2,fish
3,fish

So the result should only by Customer Id 1

Answer (score 0):

For a single pass answer to the revised question, try:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Order
GROUP BY Id
HAVING SUM(case when Dish = 'chicken' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   AND SUM(case when Dish = 'fish' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```